# Properly clean up SQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-delete

I have create an automation testing framework that to work, needs to create hundreds of records in SQL database (using Hibernate) now every time I create new entity/record, I am storing ID's of those entities so I can use those ID's to create a DELETE query to delete all records when not needed (to clean up after scenarios)

That's how my database cleanup script looks like (simplified)

```
private void cleanDB()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    try
    {
        String combinedQuery = "-- DB cleanup query\n";

        // disable constraints for each table in DB
        combinedQuery += Queries.createSetTablesConstraintEnabledQuery(false);

        // repeat this step for each table, adding DELETE statement like this
        combinedQuery += "DELETE FROM dbo.TableName WHERE (Id IN (" + ids + "))";

        // enable constraints for each table in DB
        combinedQuery += Queries.createSetTablesConstraintEnabledQuery(true);

        Query query = session.createNativeQuery(combinedQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        closeSession(session);
        Assert.fail("Failed cleaning Client DB! " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Now problem is, that I might be running multiple insteances of my automation testing framework (that are testing against the same database) so chances are, that cleanup procedure might be executed at the same time, other instance is cleaning database, resulting in 'deadlock'

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   **Transaction (Process ID 115) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.**    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:461)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>     ... 64 more

Any ideas how to tackle this issue? Someone suggested me that I should NOT use transactions when only executing DELETE statements, what would be best way to clean up database without locking it?

Comment: This may be totally off-topic, but wouldn't it be better for you to create an instance of database per each test run and provide proper name (e.g. `test_db_20200415_1501`) to get rid of such issues?  Then you'll be able to run your test queries and in the end drop entire database without affecting other tests.

Comment: @AlexRudenko - that is valid point, i was considering that, but I wanted to avoid that because it adds additional time to create separate databases, and I would like to avoid extending time it takes to run our pipelines. Thus wanted to run against same database.